# My phone keeps changing "wifi" word into "WLAN"

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lenovo

I have a [Lenovo A319](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a319-6789.php) with Android 4.4.2 and I have noticed a weird thing.

My phone keeps changing the word "wifi" into "WLAN" whenever it finds it.

If I type "wifi" anywhere on the phone (notepad app, browser, etc...) it will change it to "**WLAN**". This happens no matter what I wrote it like "wi-fi", "Wifi", "WI-FI" and so on...

I also noticed that it is even changing it in the networking data of installed apps.

Why is this happening, is it a bug in Android or just in my phone, or is it a prank !!

Comment: Is this basically autocorrecting it when you type, or is it also replacing it in places such as quick settings, the settings app, etc?

Comment: It is replacing it everywhere when typing, in settings, inside apps, i had an app that fetches data from the internet, tha data contained the word "wifi", even that was changed !!

Comment: If it's just when you're typing, this could be part of a custom dictionary for your keyboard or something that someone has set it to correct it to, however it does seem strange and a but beyond that. With the app, it simply replaces WiFi with WLAN even though the data fetched off the internet definitely had WiFi?